# How to access the Internet through a sheevaplug connected to a WRT54G router?

Tags: ssh, ping, wrt54g, sheevaplug

I'm having trouble accessing the Internet from my [sheevaplug](http://www.plugcomputer.org/development-kits/plug-computer-basic.html).

I recently purchased a sheevaplug and connected it to my Linksys WRT54G router. The sheevaplug never showed up in the list of dhcp clients (under Status -> Local Network → DHCP Clients Table), but I was able to guess what the IP address would be and connect to the sheevaplug by way of ssh from my laptop computer:

```
ssh root@192.168.1.108
```

At the sheevaplug command prompt, I'm unable to ping Google:

```
ping www.google.com
```

I'm able to ping Google without any problem from my laptop computer, which is connected to the Internet through the same router. The sheevaplug is connected to the router through an eithernet cable, whereas my laptop is connect though wifi.

Any suggestions on how to configure my system so the sheevaplug can reach the Internet? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the plug is not showing up in the DHCP registry, it might not also be receiving dns info to resolve the name.

If you can statically set your DNS server on the sheevaplug, try 8.8.8.8 (google's public DNS Server). You can also try pinging that directly and seeing if that works.

**EDIT:** With more research I found that the Sheevaplug is automatically set to ignore DNS servers from DHCP. Follow these instructions to start full DHCP:

The DHCP client is configured to ignore any DNS servers returned by the DHCP server and use 127.0.0.1 instead, while there is no local DNS server. Consequently, you won't be able to connect to any hosts by name until you fix this. In order to fix it: 
Edit /etc/dhcp3/dhclient.conf and comment out or delete the line "supersede domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;". 
Run "dhclient eth0". 
Try "ping kernel.org" - it should work.

from: http://www.grantlucas.com/archive/november/2009/setting-sheevaplug-media-server

Comment: I would like to know how to get it to show up in the DHCP registry if possible.

Comment: @Gwen Updated my post with some info that might help.